# Pattern matching, which language first had it

Tags: history, programming

Which programming language was the first to use [pattern match](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching)?
The oldest ones I know are:

- Prolog 1972
- ML 1973

Are there languages older that have pattern matching?

Edit:

By pattern matching I mean you can use patterns to control the flow of exection, like in Haskell for example:

```
factorial 0 = 1

factorial n = n *factorial  (n-1)
```

Here we match with 0 if we call (factorial 0).
And we match n if we call (factorial 1).
You can use _ if you want to match with anything and you have list matching too with (head:tail) .

You can use this to replace all if else and switch statments and it can do more.

Comment: Can you narrow down what you mean by pattern matching? Do you mean reg-ex style? or something more sophisticated. Does the matcher have to be an intrinsic part of the language or just easy to implement in it? Taking a fairly broad definition of the answer, I would think that Lisp came first, at a guess.

Comment: @JeremP yes, your right I mean like in Haskell pattern matching ... I've added more discrption to the post.

Comment: Are you confusing recursion with pattern matching? Your example shows recursion....

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015684/f-version-of-haskell-pattern-match/11015750

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Refal](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Refal) (conceived 1966, implemented 1968) is a language built upon the idea of structured pattern-matching.

A function definition is a sequence of constructs "pattern = replacement", operating on the function argument that consists of a sequence of terms.

Each term is either a symbol (a character or a meta-symbol like a number of a function ID), or a parenthesized sequence of terms.

A pattern is a similarly-structured sequence with free variables that can match individual symbols, terms or "expressions" (sequences of terms), as well as literal symbols.

A replacement is a sequence of terms with potential function call terms that use magic parentheses and the sequence in parentheses starts from a function ID.

The examples on the Wiki page, like

```
 Fact { 0 = 1;
    s.N = <* s.N <Fact <- s.N 1>>>; }
```

don't do the language justice; the main feature of the language is the ability to pattern-match structured data.

The language had a counter-culture popularity in the programming circles in the USSR after the author had to emigrate to the U.S. in 1977, and was taught by the author, [Valentin Turchin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valentin_Turchin), in the City College of New York until his death in 2010. Now, unfortunately, the reference links on the Refal wiki page are also dead.

Searching for "refal" on [Github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=refal&type=) returned 1599 matches, though.

Answer (score 7):

Probably the [first language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_programming_languages) to use string patterns was [COMIT in 1957](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMIT). This was the predecessor to [SNOBOL in 1962](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNOBOL) from which it is considered most string processing language features claim their origin.

Comment: SNOBOL was my first thought on this (I wasn't aware of COMIT), but then *string* pattern matching is somewhat different in scope to the *structured* pattern matching used by Prolog & ML family languages, so I'm not convinced they should really be considered the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

A form of structural pattern matching is presented in a 1963 paper *[METEOR: A LISP Interpreter for String Transformations](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/6106)* by Danied Bobrow.

(Don't be fooled by the term "string").